# Is there any special relation between squared root of sum of squares and sum of the values themselves?

Tags: summation, direct-sum, sums-of-squares

I mean, is there any relation between $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ... + a_n$ and $\sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 + ... + a_n^2}$ ? This relation can be of any kind or any use.

***Thank you all in advance.***

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I think you mean $\sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 + \ldots + a_n^2}$, right?

Comment: As it is currently written the root of squared sum, $\sqrt{(a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ... + a_n)^2}$, is simply $|a_1 + a_2 +... a_n$
Note by convention a $\sqrt{}$  with no other notation is always positive or possibly zero..

Comment: @HaydnGwyn Yes, you're right. :) edited.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that all the $a_i \geqslant 0$ then it is true that the quadratic mean is greater than the arithmetic mean:
$$\left(\frac{1}{n}(a_1^2+a_2^2+\cdots+a_n^2)\right)^{\frac12} \geqslant \frac{1}{n}(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)$$
or
$$n(a_1^2+a_2^2+\cdots+a_n^2) \geqslant (a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)^2$$

Comment: There was a mistake in my question. That was edited. Please, see it again if possible. Thank you.

Comment: @elyar - I think my answer still stands.

Comment: So, I have to thank you.